# get data between inverted commas and more

Tags: php, xml, arrays, parsing, tags

i have aproblem for a few days right now :s ...
I'm trying to get some changing data inside a string, the string is something like this:

```
<docdata>
 <!-- News Identifier -->
        <doc-id id-string ="YBY15349" />

        <!-- Date of issue -->
        <date.issue norm ="2012-09-22 19:52" />
        <!-- Date of release -->
        <date.release norm ="2012-09-22 19:52" />
      </docdata>
```

What i need is only the **date** inside the **"2012-09-22 19:52"**  , the string its stored in some type of xml, malformed by the way. So i can't use normal xml parser, i load/read the file already to change some charset

```
    $fname = $file;
    $fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
    $content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));
    str_replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>", $content); 
etc..
```

this work like a charm, but with the string i cant use it.
I try with preg_match_all but i can`t get it right.
Its there a simple way to search this value

`<date.issue norm ="2012-09-22 19:52" />`

and get just the date in a variable?

thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: `file_get_contents` is easier for your first 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

Consequently, your code would become:

```
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$content = str_replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>", $content);
preg_match_all('/date\.issue norm ="([^"]+)" /', $content, $date);
```

The default behavior is to store the parenthesized matches in the array `$date[1]`. Therefore, you might loop through `$date[1][0]`, `$date[1][1]`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks Sara, that work great!! and answer me some future problems. 
Thanks to all for taking the time !! :)

Comment: No problem! SO tip: You can accept the answer that you think is best by clicking the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression to match the following:

```
<date.issue norm ="2012-09-22 19:52" />
```

Would be:

```
/<date\.issue\s*norm\s*="([^"]*)"/
```

In code:

```
preg_match_all('/<date\.issue\s*norm\s*="([^"]*)"/', $content, $matches);
// $matches[1] contains all the dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
fopen($filename)
```

use

```
$filename = '/path/to/file.xml';
$filearray = file($filename) // pulls the while file into an array by lines

$searchstr = 'date.issue';

foreach($filearray as $line) {
   if(stristr($line,$searchstr)) { // <-- forgot the )
      $linearray = explode('"',$line);
      // your date should be $linearray[1];
      echo $linearray[1]."\n";  // to test your output
      // rest of your code here
   }
}
```

this way you search the whole file for your search string and the malformed xml shouldnt be a problem.